# grep on multiple files, output to multiple files named after the original files

Tags: shell, variables, unix, awk, grep

I have a folder with 64 items in it, numbered like this: 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-1 …
What I want to do is grep the file 1-1 for a specific pattern, have the output saved to a new file named 1-1a, then move on to file 1-2, and so on. The pattern stays the same for all 64 files.

I tried variations with `find` and `-exec grep 'pattern' "{} > {}a"` but it seems like I can't use {} twice on one line and still have it interpreted as a variable. I'm also open to suggestions using awk or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be easy with awk

```
awk '/pattern/{print > FILENAME "a"}' *
```

In order to use find, replace `*` with the results of a `find` command:

```
awk '/pattern/{print > FILENAME "a"}' $(find ...)`
```

... but do that only if the file names do not contain special characters (e.g. spaces) and the list doesn't grow too long. Use a loop in these cases.

Comment: Thank you, this works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `find` command

```sh
find . -name '*[0-9]-*[0-9]' -exec bash -c '
for f; do grep "pattern" "$f" > "${f}a"; done' - {} +
```

Note that you can run this command multiple times and it won't keep creating files like `13-3aa` or `13-3aaa` etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but all I get is a file called 13-3a as output, with nothing being grepped.
Edit: Changing the + at the end to \; makes it run through all files, but the pattern is still not searched. I should update my OS …

Comment: Sorry I had made a mistake that is fixed now. When using `+` after `-exec` it avoids creating `bash` subprocess for each entry and passes multiple filenames at once to `-exec` command.